# Delay population of a sub menu in Windows and C++

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cmenu, trackpopupmenu

I have an C++ MFC CMenu based context menu object that has several menu items and one menu item is a popup menu (ie has a sub menu). Populating the sub menu is a time intensive process so I don't want to actually populate it until the user clicks on it.

How do I detect the display of the sub menu so I can only populate it when the user clicks on it?

I'm using TrackPopupMenu to display the menu to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [WM_INITMENUPOPUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646347.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the WM_CONTEXTMENU message in the window. Then you can do whatever you like in response to that message.